# OpenGL glReadPixels returns 0

Tags: c++, opengl-3

When Im rendering to on-screen buffer everything goes fine, but when reading pixels from FrameBuffer with glReadPixels it always returns 0.

The pseudocode is the following:

**Bind texture to FrameBuffer:**

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
int width, height;
width = 2;
height = 2;
float texture_data[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, texture_data);
GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer); 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer); 
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0); 
GLint texture_coord_attribute = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texture_coord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texture_coord_attribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(texture_coord_attribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    sizeof(vertices[0]), (void*)(sizeof(float) * 5));
```

**Fragment/Vertex shaders:**

```
static const char* vertex_shader_text =
"#version 330\n""
"attribute vec2 vPos;\n"
"attribute vec2 texture_coord;\n"
"varying vec2 Texcoord;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_Position = vec4(vPos, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"    Texcoord = texture_coord;\n"
"}\n";

static const char* fragment_shader_text =
"#version 330\n"
"varying vec2 Texcoord;\n"
"uniform sampler2D tex;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_FragColor = texture(tex, Texcoord);\n"
"}\n";
```

**Read Pixels in Main loop:**

```
glViewport(0, 0, 720, 480);
glUseProgram(program);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

GLubyte pixels[3] = {0};
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels(360, 240, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
// Any value returns 0 not only 360 and 240
printf("|%f||%f||%f|\n", pixels[0], pixels[1], pixels[2]);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

This is the pipeline I follow. What is wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: @Rabbid76 glTexImage2D is my original code, I have added to the post to clarify the main pipeline.  On the other hand, glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER ) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) returns TRUE after drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5th and 6th parameter (`format` and `type`) of [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) specifies the format and data type of the **target** pixel data.

Since you want to read to a buffer with the element data type `GLubyte`, the type has to be `GL_BYTE`.

Change your code like this:

```
glReadPixels(360, 240, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_BYTE, pixels);
```

Or read the data to a buffer of type  `GLfloat`:

```
GLfloat pixels[3];
glReadPixels(360, 240, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
```

Note, what you do, is to read 12 bytes (`sizeof(float)*3`) to a buffer with a size of 3 bytes (`GLubyte pixels[3]`). This means a part of the floating point value which represents the red color channel is stored to the buffer. The rest overwrites some memory with bad access.

Comment: I am confused to see the use of `GL_FLOAT` here, because [the documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) says this parameter "Must be one of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1.". **Can we use GL_FLOAT or not?**

Comment: Sorry, the documentation I point to is for OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: @yuqli The question is about OpenGL. OpenGL ES is a different specification. `GL_FLOAT` is not supported in OpenGL ES 2.0, but it is supported in OpenGL ES 3.0 (see [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml#:~:text=glReadPixels%20returns%20pixel%20data%20from,parameters%20are%20set%20with%20glPixelStorei.)) as in OpenGL.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification :)